# How to edit the contents of a list box, from a text box in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a library application with a listbox containing a list of books on the main form. I have created an edit form for the books. I want to be able to change the contents of the selected item in the listbox by changing the text in the textboxes of the edit form. Any suggestions how I could do this?

Main form:

```
private void lstBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentBook = lstBooks.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
        frmEditBook tempEditBook = new frmEditBook(lstBooks);
        tempEditBook.Show();
        frmkeepBookstore.Hide();

    }
```

Edit form:

```
private void frmEditBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtName.Text = listBoxBooks.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxBooks.Items.Add(txtName.Text.Replace);
        frmBookstore.frmkeepBookstore.Show();
        this.Close(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your edit form, have a public property for your text

```
public string NewText
{
    get
    {
        return txtName.Text;
    }
}
```

And then when changing the item in the listbox, simply use the following procedure.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code from above
    lstBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
    frmEditBook tempEditBook = new frmEditBook(lstBooks);
    tempEditBook.Show();
    frmkeepBookstore.Hide();
    //My line
    lstBooks.Items[lstBooks.SelectedIndex] = tempEditBook.NewText;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: 'prjBooks.frmBookstore' does not contain a definition for 'NewText' and no extension method 'NewText' accepting a first argument of type 'prjBooks.frmBookstore' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) How can I fix this?

Comment: I've fixed it ^_^, I used the wrong form for the replacing line, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be very simple if you call the new form with ShowDialog() instead of Show(). In your frmEditBook you should define the property

```
public string Txt {get; set;}
```

and set it at `btnSave_Click`

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxBooks.Items.Add(txtName.Text);
    Txt = txtName.Text;
    frmBookstore.frmkeepBookstore.Show();
    this.Close(); 
}
```

and use the variable after the edit form is closed:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
    frmEditBook tempEditBook = new frmEditBook(lstBooks);
    tempEditBook.ShowDialog();

    //tempEditBook.Txt here is your text
    lstBooks.SelectedItem = tempEditBook.Txt;

    frmkeepBookstore.Hide();

}
```

Comment: This gives me the following errors: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'

Comment: Cannot convert method group 'Replace' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add(object)' has some invalid arguments - what am I doing wrong?